# Linking two active directories through LDAP to Alfresco

Tags: active-directory, ldap, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to link two active directories to Alfresco through LDAP. 
I have added the following line to alfresco-global.properties:

```
authentication.chain=alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm,ldap-ad1:ldap-ad,ldap-ad2:ldap-ad
```

I have made two sub-folders ldap-ad1 and ldap-ad2 in the folder `C:\Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco\WEB-INF\classes\alfresco\subsystems\Authentication\ldap-ad`. And placed ldap-ad-authentication.properties file in both these sub-folders. Corresponding configuration for both ADs have been added to these files.

When I add these Active directory setting individually to the alfresco-global.properties, they work and the AD gets synced to Alfresco.

But the chaining doesn't work and only the users from one of the AD are seen. Both the server names, user name and passwords are correct as they work individually.

I have added these lines to the default-synchronization.properties file to sync the AD at regular intervals:

```
synchronization.synchronizeChangesOnly=false
synchronization.import.cron=0 0/1 * * * ?
```

Can anyone please advise as what might be wrong?

Thanks !!

Comment: Anything in the logs about errors or problems? It ought to work just fine...

Comment: Does switching the order of your chain cause anything to change?

Comment: Hi @Gagravarr, It gives this error: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Boolean' for property 'allowGuestLogin'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid boolean value [${ldap.authentication.allowGuestLogin}]. It is not able to see this value defined in the two files inside the ldap-ad1 and ldap-ad2 folder. If I add this property to the alfresco-global.properties the error goes away but then it throws error for the other properties similarly.

Comment: Hi @JeffPotts, yes i tried switching but it still gives the same errors.

Comment: That property is defined in the sample `config/alfresco/subsystems/Authentication/ldap-ad/ldap-ad-authentication.properties` file. Make sure your ldap properties file is taken from the same version of Alfresco as you're using, and don't delete any keys!

Comment: @Gagravarr its taken from the same version. I deleted the ldap-ad-authentication.properties from the ldap-ad folder and placed it in ldap-ad1 and ldap-ad2 sub-folders. What do you mean by keys? Can you please explain.

Comment: Properties files are made up of key-value pairs. Leave them all in! Just change the ones needed for your setup

Comment: Yes, I didn't delete any of them. Just changed the ones required for my AD settings. I even tried naming the properties files as one-ldap-ad-authentication.properties and two-ldap-ad-authentication.properties and placed them directly in the ldap-ad folder. Now the previous errors goes away, but Alfresco just fetches groups from one AD, though in the log it shows it has synchronized with both.

Comment: Adding the Authentication folder to the path /shared/classes/alfresco/extension/subsytems did the trick.